# Create a Circle on Clicking Button JavaFX

Tags: javafx, netbeans, scenebuilder

I try to create a new shape (Circle for this example) by clicking a button.
I'm not completely in JavaFX yet so there are small problems in executing. I'm familiar with changing sizes, colors and so on of existing shapes, but I don't know how to create something on a click. 
My Controller and my Main so far:

```
package javafxapplication1;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Tom
 */
public class JavaFXApplication1 extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

--------------------here starts the controller---------------

```
package javafxapplication1;

import java.awt.Paint;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

/**
 *
 * @author Tom
 */
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button btn;


    @FXML
    public void pressButton(ActionEvent event){
       Circle kreis1;
        kreis1 = new Circle(200, 200, 10, Color.BLACK);

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    
}
```

Could you please help me? I need these basics but can't find any explanation online! Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually almost did it, only missing two things.

First of all you did not include `FXMLDocument.fxml` but I assume `pressButton` method is bound to the `onAction` event of the button.

You created a `Circle` on your button action, now you need to add that circle to a pane. Without adding to a pane that circle would not be seen.

For example if we had this fxml;

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="root" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="btn" layoutX="271.0" layoutY="331.0"  onAction="#pressButton" text="Button" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

We have an AnchorPane with `fx:id="root"` and we want to add circles to that on button action.

Now in our controller class, we need to bind the AnchorPane

```
@FXML private AnchorPane root;
```

Now just add your circle to this root in your pressButton method.

```
@FXML
public void pressButton(ActionEvent event){
   Circle kreis1;
   kreis1 = new Circle(200, 200, 10, Color.BLACK);
   root.getChildren().add(kreis1);
}
```

That would create a circle in x,y coordinates 200,200.

For example this pressButton method would create circles with random coordinates and random colors in the Pane.

```
@FXML
public void pressButton(ActionEvent event) {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int  x = rand.nextInt(500) + 1;
    int  y = rand.nextInt(400) + 1;
    int r = rand.nextInt(40) + 10;
    double red = rand.nextDouble();
    double green = rand.nextDouble();
    double blue = rand.nextDouble();

    Circle kreis1;
    kreis1 = new Circle(x, y, r, new Color(red, green, blue,1));

    root.getChildren().add(kreis1);
}
```